# Set height based on largest TD in TR

Tags: html, css

I am building an HTML table and using Internet Explorer 11. In each TR are several TD with embedded elements of varying size. I inspected the page through IE DOM Explorer and think I know what is going on. Generally the textarea is the largest element (at 167px as per the CSS) but sometimes one of the other td elements will be bigger (say td1=300px). The problem I have is that I want the text area to fill out to 300px. I can see though that the height is inheriting from td id="td3" which is still 167px. Is there a way I can get td id="td3" to get the height from the largest sibling td in a tr.

The HTML looks something like this

```
<thead>
   ...
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">[Dynamic Text1]</td>
        <td id="td2">[Dynamic Text2]</td>
        <td id="td3"><textarea class="ta"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ....
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
.ta{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 167px
}
```

---

One thing is I notice Chrome does what I want but I would prefer a solution that conforms with the standards

Comment: There are numerous errors in your code: **(1)** the proper tag to close a td is `</td>`, not `<t/td>` **(2)** You did not close the textarea tag, use `</textarea>` **(3)** You did not properly close the third `td`. **(4)** You need a semicolon after the `min-height` line. Fixing all of these errors makes it run correctly.

Comment: Though, to be pedantic, one does not need semicolon after last property, but omitting it makes it *easy to mangle* on edit.

Comment: in case you can still help. I m seeing the above work in Chrome but not Internet Explorer 11 or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have HTML errors (try validating with w3.org validator). That is often the cause of display bugs that crop up between different rendering engines. Anyway, your example seems to work fine here:

```
td {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: lightblue;
    vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kg3P5/2/

Comment: One interesting point. In internet explorer, looking at the computed properties the height of the tr is set to 242px. On Internet Explorer the height is set to "auto". These are both computed (not coming from any CSS). I see this on both the jsfiddle and my project

Comment: ah. Sorry I don't have access to IE right now, but updated example by setting textarea to display: block; Please try it again, see if there is a difference in IE. The reasoning is that textareas are natively inline so height might not apply unless you make it 'block' level.

Comment: unfortunately not. I will keep digging around